# How to get selected column's text In Gtk-rs

Tags: rust, gtk

I have got a question here. So I have a `TreeView` in Gtk-rs which is linked with a `ListStore`. The `ListStore` has 3 columns but I am only displaying 2 columns. My problem is very simple, basically I want that whenever a user clicks on a row of the `TreeView`, the program prints the fourth column in to `stdout`.

The codebase is huge so I cannot share the code, as the code is distributed over 50 files. Also it will be open-source but not yet. So I am stuck here with this problem. I have tried Reddit but no luck.

Any help is greatly welcomed. Just share a small code snippet with a possible explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to manage the `row_activated` signal. If you want the user to activate the row with a single click instead of a double click, as you seem to suggest, you need to set the `activate-on-single-click` property to true.

Then it is just a matter of getting the model from the tree (or from some captured state), get the `iter` from the clicked `path`, the value from the `iter` and the wanted column, and cast it to the proper type.

```
tree.set_activate_on_single_click(true);
tree.connect_row_activated(
    |tree, path, _col| {
        let model = tree.get_model().unwrap();
        let iter = model.get_iter(path).unwrap();
        let text = model.get_value(&iter, 2).get::<String>().unwrap();
        println!("{}", text);
    }
);
```

I've added a few `unwrap()` calls to make the code simpler. You should check if any of these can fail in your application and handle those cases gracefully.